# Java - How to calculate age by considering birthday date on database

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I'm trying to solve this problem but i can't find a good solution.
When an user register on my website, among other data, I'm asking for the birthday date.
As well as the birthday date, I'd also like to add on the database the actual age of the user so, in order to do that, I'm using this code (added into the class User.java):

```
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

private int actualAge = ageCalculator(dateOfBirth);

public int ageCalculator(LocalDate data) {
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
    if(data != null) {
        return Period.between(data, d).getYears();
    }else {
        return //error message;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code, is working just in the right moment an user register on the website.
For example: let's say tomorrow I'll turn 30 and I register on the website today (that I'm still 29). So, on the database will be added the age "29". But tomorrow, that I'll turn 30, the age on the database will still be 29.
There is a way to automatically update the age?
I was thinking about to get the birthday date of every user with a Query - by month - and update the age.
Let me explain better: now we are in June, so with the query I'll select all the users who were born in June and if the month and the day of their birthday is the same to the month and day of the LocalDate.now(), then I increase the age by 1.
Do you have any suggestion? Thanks for the help/advices.

Comment: Just store the birthday in de DB and calculate the age whenever you need it?

Comment: Storing a birthdate makes sense, updating the "age" does not. It's trivial to calculate an age given a birthdate (today - birthdate = age). However, it will take work to update the age along the way, every day, forever, for all users, also handling cases when the "age updater" doesn't run, crashes for some reason, etc. Just stick with birthdate.

Comment: As everyone else has said, store the birthday.

Comment: This is a good example why rule no. 1 in database design is don't store redundant data, data that can be calculated from other data (or found elsewhere) (unless you have a very strong argument why you really have to).

Comment: As for storing birth date, that is a vital piece of private information which should not be casually recorded. Doing so may even be a violation of privacy laws in some jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store the age because is always changing. Age should be calculated every time you query persons information. You already have a solution in Java, you could also do it using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but since you seem to really need to do it, you could use Spring @Scheduler annotation and create a Scheduler that will run once every 24 hours getting the age and the birthday of every user.
You could then compare the dates just like you mentioned, using:
`Period.between(birthday, now).getYears();`
If the result is the same as the age column, don't do anything. If it's not, update the age.